# Next.js - Render modal with data based on router query params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a feed that displays cards. The cards each open a modal which displays further information related to the card, with props being passed down two levels. This all works fine, until I add Next Link for modal routing. After Next Link is added and I give the modal a URL route, data rendered in the modal window is the same for every entry, and is always the data for the last entry in the data.map in the feed.

What is causing the problem with the incorrect data displayed in the modal window when we use the simple modal routing, please? There are codesandbox links below for the working and non-working examples.

Feed:

```
export default function IndexPage() {
const data = [
{
  _id: "x1",
  name: "name_1",
  icon: "url1",
  price: "18"
},
{
  _id: "x2",
  name: "name_2",
  icon: "url2",
  price: "27"
},
{
  _id: "x3",
  name: "name_3",
  icon: "url3",
  price: "37"
},
{
  _id: "x4",
  name: "name_4",
  icon: "url4",
  price: "25"
}
];

return (
<div>
  {data.map((data) => (
    <Card key={data._id} data={data} />
  ))}
</div>
);
}
```

The Card:

```
const card = ({ data }) => {
const router = useRouter();

return (
<>
  <Link href={`/?postId=${data._id}`} as={`/view-post/${data.name}`}>
    <h1>{data.name}</h1>
  </Link>
  <Modal
    isOpen={!!router.query.postId}
    onRequestClose={() => router.push("/")}
    contentLabel="Post modal"
  >
    <ModalContent data={data} />
  </Modal>
  </>
  );
  };

 export default card;
```

If we change the code in the Card component and remove the (simple) modal routing code, data is displayed in the ModalContent correctly:

```
<>
  <div onClick={openModal}>
    <h1>{data.name}</h1>
  </div>
  <Modal
    isOpen={modalIsOpen}
    onRequestClose={closeModal}
    contentLabel="Post modal"
  >
    <ModalContent data={data} />
  </Modal>
</>
```

ModalContent is just a simple component showing two items of data:

```
const DomainModalContent = ({ data }) => {
return (
<>
  <div>{data.name}</div>
  <div>{data.price}</div>
</>
);
};
```

Please view the following working examples:

With modal routing (data displayed is incorrect):  https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-johnson-4jq6r?file=/pages/index.js

Normal modals (data is correct):  https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-proskuriakova-uggmn?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: You're actually rendering 4 modals (1 for each card) at once, since each card renders a modal which is displayed if the router's query object contains a **truthy** `postId`. You probably want to change that conditional for the `isOpen` prop to something like `router.query.postId === data._id`. You should also change your `card` component to pascal case (Card).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Ryan, that works. If you put it in an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as correct for you if you want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I commented with a fix, I would recommend checking for a valid postId on the `router.query` object in the cards' parent component, then finding and storing the data item associated with that id. You could then render a single `Modal` in that same parent (passing the stored data item as a prop), and display it conditionally, based on the value (e.g. truthy) of the stored data item.